# In lme4, how to specify a one-way ANOVA within or between subject?

Tags: r, mixed-model, anova, lme4-nlme, random-effects-model

Using the lme4 package for mixed effect models in R, I am trying to figure out what is the difference in modelling a one-way ANOVA within subject and a one-way ANOVA between subject.

Suppose first, that each subject see all three treatments (A, B and C). In each treatment, each subject gives me one measure (DV). I can model this within-subject design as follows:

```
lmer(DV ~ treatment + (1|subject), data = My_Data)
```

Now, suppose each subject sees only one treatment. What is the corresponding model? Would it be the same? If yes, how will lmer() know that it is a between subject design?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The model formula will be the same in both cases. lmer knows whether the factor is within or between.

We can see this with a simple simulation. First, simulate a within-subject design:

```
> set.seed(15)
> dt.se <- expand.grid(subject = 1:10, treatmentWithin = as.factor(c("A", "B", "C")))
>
> dt.se$DV <- dt.se$subject * as.numeric(dt.se$treatmentWithin) + rnorm(nrow(dt.se), 0, 1)
>
> xtabs(~ treatmentWithin + subject, dt.se)

                subject
treatmentWithin 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
              A 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1  1
              B 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1  1
              C 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1  1
```

So we can see that each subject receives each treatment once. Then we fit the model:

```
> summary(lmm1 <- lmer(DV ~ treatmentWithin + (1|subject), data = dt.se))  
Linear mixed model fit by REML ['lmerMod']
Formula: DV ~ treatmentWithin + (1 | subject)
   Data: dt.se

REML criterion at convergence: 167.3

Scaled residuals: 
    Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
-1.5772 -0.4341  0.0261  0.4912  1.9308 

Random effects:
 Groups   Name        Variance Std.Dev.
 subject  (Intercept) 29.8     5.46    
 Residual             10.5     3.24    
Number of obs: 30, groups:  subject, 10

Fixed effects:
                 Estimate Std. Error t value
(Intercept)          5.68       2.01    2.83
treatmentWithinB     5.24       1.45    3.61
treatmentWithinC    11.29       1.45    7.78
```

Now we create a new treatment variable for a between-subject design:

```
> dt.se$treatmentBetween <- as.factor(rep(c(rep(c("A", "B", "C"), 3), "A"), 3))
> xtabs(~ treatmentBetween + subject, dt.se)

                subject
treatmentBetween 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
               A 3 0 0 3 0 0 3 0 0  3
               B 0 3 0 0 3 0 0 3 0  0
               C 0 0 3 0 0 3 0 0 3  0
```

Now we see that each subject receives only one treatment - 3 times each. So now we can fit the model with the same formula:

```
> summary(lmm2 <- lmer(DV ~ treatmentBetween + (1|subject), data = dt.se))  
Linear mixed model fit by REML ['lmerMod']
Formula: DV ~ treatmentBetween + (1 | subject)
   Data: dt.se

REML criterion at convergence: 191.9

Scaled residuals: 
    Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
-1.2516 -0.6507 -0.0686  0.3562  2.1658 

Random effects:
 Groups   Name        Variance Std.Dev.
 subject  (Intercept) 28.8     5.36    
 Residual             41.4     6.43    
Number of obs: 30, groups:  subject, 10

Fixed effects:
                  Estimate Std. Error t value
(Intercept)         11.146      3.262    3.42
treatmentBetweenB   -0.448      4.982   -0.09
treatmentBetweenC    0.590      4.982    0.12
```

Comment: In your second example, why did each subject receive the treatment 3 times? What about the very simple case where you have 10 subjects receiving one treatment one time (So overall you have 10 data points)? Would the model still be the same?

Comment: In that case the model would not be identified. You need to have repeated measures at the `subject` level in order to make random intercepts make sense. That's why each subject received the treatment 3 times in my simulation (and it was easy to modify the data to do so).